# Is the classpath exception and the GPL linking exception the same thing?

Tags: gpl, linking

I am looking at the exception to the GPL v2. The exception is "classpath exception" and "GPL linking exception".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_linking_exception also has a classpath exception.

Does "classpath exception" and "GPL linking exception" have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but I my understanding is that "GPL linking exception" refers to any linking exception applied to a GPL license by its owner. Such exceptions allow the module to be linked and distributed with other non-GPL modules.

The Classpath exception is one instance of linking exception, granted by the GNU Classpath project. Other projects, like the GCC runtime, also include custom linking exceptions.

[GPL v3 standardizes the exceptions under section 7.](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLIncompatibleLibs)

**So, briefly, the Classpath exception is one instance of GPL linking exception.**