# What is the difference between GPL classpath exception and linking exception?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, gpl-2, license

So I read that OpenJDK is under the GPLv2 with linking exception. What is a Classpath exception and a linking exception? The JDK that I'm using(Amazon Corretto which is a build of OpenJDK) is under the GPLv2 with Classpath exception. Are these 2 the same thing? Also, what is a assembly exception? Is OpenJDK fully covered by a classpath  exception?

The first answer to this post confuses me
[What is a class path exception?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/515/what-is-a-class-path-exception)

Comment: Can you clarify what confuses you about the answer to https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/515/what-is-a-class-path-exception ? That might help us is writing an answer that is not similarly confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't understand what is meant by "some of the OpenJDK" and what is the assembly exception?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the classpath exception and the GPL linking exception the same thing?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/is-the-classpath-exception-and-the-gpl-linking-exception-the-same-thing)